# node:236984) [INSPECTOR_ASYNC_STACK_TRACES_NOT_AVAILABLE] when debug a node.js app with vs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

[image]

os:          windows10 64bit
vscode:

Version: 1.37.1 (user setup)

Commit: f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35

Electron: 4.2.7

Chrome: 69.0.3497.128

Node.js: 10.11.0

V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a warning wich can be ignored, this may cause the Debugger work with all features, so if you want that fixed install x64 bit version of node.js: [image]

See [`github:vscode-chrome-debug-core#321`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/321) [`github:vscode-chrome-debug-core#328`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/328)

Comment: but it stopped the debug

Comment: It should not stop the debugger. Do you have a 64bit device?

Comment: my os is 64bit win10

Comment: ( see updated answer ), intall node.js for x64 then

Answer (score 0):

After I enabled this option in this window:

[image: screenshot]

to **automatically install the necessary tools** and reinstalled it. My debugger worked as intended and the error `[INSPECTOR_ASYNC_STACK_TRACES_NOT_AVAILABLE]` did not appear anymore.